# How to mock Boolean field? Error Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.Boolean

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to mock on field and return needed value but got error

here is error

```
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.Boolean
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
- Cannot mock wrapper types, String.class or Class.class
```

Here is my mocking

```
val isFlag : Boolean = mock()
    whenever(myObject.flag).thenReturn(isFlag)
```

The next step will be set the value